# Responsive Div with 3 columns

Tags: html, responsive

Hi have 3 divs with text, image and vídeo. On my browser look fine but when i do my page small (responsive) can't see the video and image.

```
<style type="text/css">

.wrap {
    display: table;
}

.wrap div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 20px;

}

</style>

<div class="wrap">
   <div class="">
      <span><strong>text:</strong></span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
      <span><strong>text:</strong></span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
   </div>
   <div class="">
      <img src="myimage.jpg">   
   </div>
   <div class="">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="myvideourl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>     
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to make a singler column in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Media Query with display:table-row like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .wrap div{
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align:center;

}
}
```

```css
.wrap {
    display: table;
}

.wrap div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 20px;

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .wrap div{
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align:center;

}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="">
      <span><strong>text:</strong></span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
      <span><strong>text:</strong></span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
   </div>
   <div class="">
      <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">   
   </div>
   <div class="">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="myvideourl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>     
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,html{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
}
.wrap{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
}
.sub{
        float:left;
        height:100%;
        overflow:auto;
        display:block;
        min-width:100px;
}
.sub1{
        width:calc((100% - 560px)/2);
}
.sub2{
        width:calc((100% - 560px)/2);
}
.sub3{
        width:560px;
}
iframe{
        width:calc(100% - 2px);
        height:calc(100% - 2px);
        border:1px solid black;

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
        .wrap {
          overflow-y:auto;
         }
        .wrap .sub{
                width:100%;
        }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="sub sub1 ">
      <span><strong>text:</strong></span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
      <span><strong>text:</strong></span><br>
      <span>text</span><br>
   </div>
   <div class="sub sub2">
      <img src="myimage.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="sub sub3">
      <iframe src="myvideourl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src=""></iframe>
   </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```